# Is there a best way to build an store web site?

Tags: html, database, webserver

As mentioned in the title, I would like to know how to create a good and effective store website.

I explaine: I'm currently bulding a website for a funiture store. I already coded the html & css part. When I started it, I only had in mind to create a sort of catalog of some product that the store has (With no price, in stock or not, no detail), but the more I think about it, I would like to go more further and put all the furniture the store has on the website (with price, in stock or not, with the furniture detail). But to do that, I can't only use html to add every product and remove them when it's sell out in the HTML code every time, because it will took to long for me to go into my HMTL code and update all the list of the product store. So I'm asking myself if their is way to connect the store's data base to the store web site, and when their is an edit in the database, it change it by itself into the HTML code or something like that. Or just a way to add and remove more easily product into the website. I would like to know the best way to put the whole inventory store on the web site that can be edit more easily than going into the HTML code and editing all the modification. I try to be as clear as possible, but if I didn't express myself well enough, tell me. Thx!

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: @esQmo_ Yhea I know I litle bit how work javascript and php, but never learned completly to code with these languages. I'm going to look for "Dynamic websites" on google, thank you!